# Does golang have a central repository for the downloaded third-party packages?

Tags: go, package

I'm new to Golang. As I understand, when you want to create a new Go project, we just need to create a directory. Then we point the environment variable `GOPATH` to this directory. Inside this directory, we create three subdirectories `pkg`, `src` and `bin`. Then when we execute `go get ...`, the third-party package will be installed in the `pkg` subdirectory. Later if I want to create another Go project, I create a new dir called project2 and point `GOPATH` to project2. At this time `go get ...` will download third-party package in the `pkg` subdirectory of project2. My question is, whether Go has a central repository? If not, the same package will be downloaded twice if they are used in two different projects. Is that true?

Comment: By "central repository", do you mean a single local cache? That's your GOPATH, and you can use the same GOPATH for multiple projects.

Comment: If I'm working on project1, I point the GOPATH to project1. Later I'm working on project2, should I point GOPATH to project2? If so, GOPATH is not a local cache...

Comment: GOPATH isn't the root of your project. Your project should be located at its import path under `$GOPATH/src`. See [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html)

Comment: `ln -s $GOPATH/src/github.com/user130268/my-cool-project ~/dev/my-cool-project` is your friend

Comment: @Plato, I'd say the `CDPATH` env. variable understood by most interactive shells is your better friend.

Answer (score 8):

I guess now there is https://gocenter.jfrog.com/ 
More info in this blog https://jfrog.com/blog/go-at-full-speed-with-gocenter

Comment: Bintray/GoCenter is being decommissioned https://jfrog.com/blog/into-the-sunset-bintray-jcenter-gocenter-and-chartcenter/ . So this not a good alternative in the close future.

Answer (score 7):

There is no central repository of go packages. Go always is looking for packages either in GOPATH or GOROOT. go get simply downloads packages using git or mercurial. I recommend you to read 
https://golang.org/doc/code.html
and https://peter.bourgon.org/go-best-practices-2016/#repository-structure

GOPATH simply tells go compiler where to search for `src`, `pkg` directories.

Answer (score 3):

> Later if I want to create another Go project, I create a new dir called project2 and point GOPATH to project2
>   …
>   My question is, whether Go has a central repository? If not, the same package will be downloaded twice if they are used in two different projects. Is that true?

No, there is no central repository for Go code. However, it is also not true that the packages will always be downloaded twice.

The misconception here is that `GOPATH` points to an individual project: it does not. Instead, `GOPATH` points to an *environment* where all of your packages live; it is where `go get` will download packages, and where `go build` will look for packages when building.

Instead of changing `GOPATH` for every project, you should set `GOPATH` once and put all of your projects in `$GOPATH/src/` (your projects don't contain an `src/` directory, they go *in* the `src/` directory).

So for example, the entire tree might look like:

```
$GOPATH/src/bitbucket.org/ (or GitHub, or your website, or whatever)
├── YourProject
└── AnotherProject
```

---

### Update

It is worth noting that this answer is no longer correct. Now that Go Modules are the normal versioning mechanism for Go code and `$GOPATH` is being phased out, a central proxy has been setup that routes all requests for packages through Google servers where the various tagged versions of the package can be cached. A separate checksum database keeps hashes for every package that are audit-able and can help you detect if a package author has changed an already released tag. All of this isn't a central repository in the same sense that PyPi (in the Python world) or NPM (for JavaScript) are a repo: the packages are still fetched from their source control, but because all packages are routed through the proxy by default it serves a similar purpose. For more information see https://proxy.golang.org/

Answer (score 3):

Recently, a new site that collects information about Go packages has emerged:
https://go.dev/.

> go.dev is the hub for Go users providing centralized and curated resources from across the Go ecosystem.

It is an official companion website to golang.org. It does not qualify for a repository, such as cpan, nmpjs, nuget or crates. For external packages, it simply links to their respective Github pages.

> Go.dev is currently in MVP status. We’re proud of what we’ve built and excited to share it with the community. We hope you find value and joy in using go.dev. Go.dev only has a small portion of features we intend to build, and we are actively seeking feedback

But as is written it the about page, it is still in early development. Maybe one day (hopefully) it shall become a fully featured code repository.

Comment: Very helpful because you can see how often a package is imported (data is from public repos).

Comment: This is a more correct answer (now) than the answers accepted when OP asked the question.  Go.dev is a central *index* for packages, although the packages themselves are posted elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

### 2024 Update

There is now an official registry of Go packages:

- [pkg.go.dev](https://pkg.go.dev/)

The packages are still hosted in a decentralized way, e.g. on GitHub.

pkg.go.dev allows for searching inside of both the standard library and third party packages, shows licenses, documentation, links to repositories.
The older [godoc.org](https://godoc.org/) now redirects to pkg.go.dev.

See also:

- [Next steps for pkg.go.dev](https://go.dev/blog/pkg.go.dev-2020) (Julie Qiu, 31 January 2020)
- [Redirecting godoc.org requests to pkg.go.dev](https://go.dev/blog/godoc.org-redirect) (Julie Qiu, 15 December 2020)
- [A new search experience on pkg.go.dev](https://go.dev/blog/pkgsite-search-redesign) (Julie Qiu, 9 November 2021)